# Why do I get different outputs when running my shellscript manually from when I run it with cron?

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have a fairly simple shell script (`foo.sh`) that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "$USER,$(date)," `binary -flags | sed -e '1,30d'`;
exit 0;
```

This script is supposed to prepare some output which will then be appended to a text file, like so:

```
foo.sh >> data.csv
```

When I run the above on a root prompt, it works fine. However, when I type the exact same command into my (root) crontab which looks like this:

```
05 * * * * /root/foo.sh >> /path/to/data.csv
```

The crontab output differs! I wasn't expecting this and I can't understand why. See examples below:

```
Expected, normal output from running my .sh (example):
Fri Jun 14 16:32:34 CEST 2013,20130614163304,268828672,71682561

The output written to the file by cron:
Fri Jun 14 16:32:34 CEST 2013,
```

The rights on the binary run in the .sh looks like this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root
```

Why does the output differ? How can I get the correct output into my CSV file?

Comment: specify the full path to binary or add it to `PATH` in the crontab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't count on having the same [environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) in a program run via `cron` as when you run it interactively. There are two differences most likely to matter in this instance:

1. The current working directory
2. The `PATH`

As `jordanm` commented above, one or both of these in combination is causing the script to not find your `binary` program.

If you look at your local system mail (e.g. by running `mailx`) you will probably find messages complaining about this failure.

It is standard practice when writing `crontab` entries and scripts intended to be run by `cron` to hard-code paths to known locations of programs.

Comment: "It is standard practice when writing crontab entries and scripts intended to be run by cron to hard-code paths to known locations of programs." -- thank you, if I had known this, I could have avoided this issue. In this case, I solved it by creating a symlink at `/bin/bar` instead. By the way, something that helped me troubleshoot the error was appending `2>/root/error.out` which showed me the actual error.